# Screen recording software for Chrome OS

Tags: video, screen-recording, webcam, chrome-os

I wish to start a YouTube channel playing *City of Steam*, and some other games like *Happy Wheels*.

There are many services such as [Screencastify](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screencastify-screen-vide/mmeijimgabbpbgpdklnllpncmdofkcpn?hl=en) which will record the screen, record my voice and embed a facecam into the video, however they do not record system audio. is there a suitable app which will do this?

I basically need a *full screen, audio, webcam* recording software that will allow me to make file for uploading to YouTube.

Requirements:

- Record screen with reasonable quality
- Record mic audio
- Record game audio
- Embed facecam

Comment: Did you check all the [other screen recorder questions](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=screen+record) on this site?

Comment: Not all, but I did do my research, which led me to screencastify. I require something that works on Chrome OS, making a lot of the questions irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TechSmith Snagit for Google Chrome™ is a free screen capture and recording app that works on Chromebooks or in the Chrome browser. You can record your screen and narrate as you go to record quick lessons. You have lot of [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tfucb1gy8VA) on [youtube](http://youtu.be/je6c7yhAfts?t=1m28s) explaining how to do it.

Comment: How many FPS does it record at? I've only would recorders which record at 10FPS

Comment: I think that depends on your CPU. But it's set on maximum 15 FPS.

Comment: It no longer supports or allows re-installing (or rather installing) on browser. And desktop version is commercial