# Screen recording tool that records both Speaker o/p as well as mic input

Tags: gratis, open-source, screen-recording

There's a software named Snag it. That works just perfect, but it's a commercial licensed and my company policy says, it isn't worth investing.

Any free/open source software that meet this requirement? I've tried Camstudio and ShareX, but both have either "Virtual Audio capture" or "Internal mic/Headset mic" capture. Not both sources.

It would help me if I can know a way to enable both audio sources at once either or yet another **software that enables recording audio from mic as well as speaker and record screen.**

note: [This](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14987/screen-recording-software-for-chrome-os) question and other similar questions aren't helping. Either answer is not applicable or no longer valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Acethinker's Free Recorder](https://acethinker.com/free-screen-recorder), [Apowersoft's Recorder](https://www.apowersoft.com/free-online-screen-recorder) and [oCam](http://ohsoft.net/eng/ocam/download.php?cate=1002) are reported to do that. You can also try to mixdown the audio that's been recorded [with proper method with Audacity](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=12&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjh-PSDraTUAhXGvY8KHU4LBikQtwIIiQEwCw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DTjVHi7erwqU&usg=AFQjCNHWD4qS2XCcqMp1hJtxCDBkb_rsew&sig2=_Jo-3ZOap_qAAC1Re-uTKg) and [VB - Voice Recorder](http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Voicemeeter/index.htm).

Comment: I'll give them a try and get back to you. Hope they are freeware or open source.

Comment: @InfantPro'Aravind' AFAIK, they're freeware. If your problem is solved, please mark as chosen solution.

Comment: They require to be accessed through browser (URL), but the requirement is met.
I'm accepting your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 9):

My Experience is:

1st Place: as Sterex suggested, [Open Broadcast Studio](https://obsproject.com/)

- OBS really provides a whole lot of flexibility for creating complex layouts which you can change on the fly while recording.

I would also Add

[ShareX](https://getsharex.com/) as a possible alternative.

Although, to be able to Capture your microphone and the System Audio at the same time you need to do a little bit of ffmpeg tweaking.

ShareX --> Task settings --> Capture --> Screen Recorder --> Screen Recording options

1. Download and install the recorder devices if they are not already installed with the buttons provided.
2. Under *Sources* select:

   a. Video Source: **screen-capture-recorder**
   b. Audio Source: **Microphone (...)**
3. Under *Additional command line Arguments* add the following:

   `-f dshow -i audio="virtual-audio-capturer" -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=longest`

*The virtual-audio-capturer is your screen audio which will gets mixed together with the other audio source defined*

Comment: Unfortunately this [breaks](https://i.imgur.com/cS4jJrM.png) "gif" screen capture. Is there a way to modify the command so it doesn't try to capture audio when recording a gif?

Comment: Maybe try putting `-err_detect ignore_err ` at the beginning the additional command line arguments ?

Comment: Thank you for the reponse! When I use 

-err_detect ignore_err -f dshow -i audio="virtual-audio-capturer" -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=longest' 

I get the [same error](https://i.imgur.com/zxFCAgJ.png)

Comment: Yea, I feared so, unfortunately I don't have ShareX installed on my current setup to do tests. When I get back to it I'll have a look and get back to you. I understand you don't want to have to change the setup and modify/remove the command/extra arguments everytime you change from gif to vid but currently I don't have any other solution for you, sorry. Happy new year!

Answer (score 3):

Open Broadcast Studio is pretty good. And it's a freeware.

https://obsproject.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Mirillis Action! screen recorder](https://mirillis.com/screen-recorder), it has a 30-day free version.
It can record system sound and your mic to different audio tracks.

Answer (score -2):

The ShareX option with the command works.

Comment: Welcome John! Can you expand your answer to include the command to which you refer?  Also, can you flush out your answer with more details and differentiate it from other answers?  Thanks!